# Couldnt run Vue.js after iframe elements loaded with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to execute Vue.js component after iframe elements created but it doesnt work.

**Here is iframe example:**

```
<div id="screen">
<!-- This iframe created after drag and drop-->
<iframe src="/elements/cover-01.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" __idm_frm__="419" __idm_id__="-2084740094" style="visibility: visible; user-select: none; overflow: hidden; height: 500px; width: 2105px; opacity: 1;">
<texeditor></texteditor>
</iframe>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

import Texteditor from './components/Texteditor.vue';

new Vue({
    el:'#screen',
    components:{Texteditor}  
});
```

**Texteditor.vue (component)**

```
<template>
    <div  @click="removeEdit">
        <p><slot></slot></p>
        <textarea  v-show="edit" class="texteditor"></textarea>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            edit: false
        }
    },
    methods:{
        toggleEdit(){
            this.edit = !this.edit;
            $('.texteditor').redactor({
                fixed:true
            });
        },
        removeEdit(){
            this.edit=false;
            $('.texteditor').destroyEditor();
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        alert();
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

I am testing with texteditor component but I couldt gain.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a typo in `<texeditor></texteditor>` it should be texTeditor

Comment: No.There is no error with typo.It works outside iframe after created iframe.But it doesnt work in iframe when created iframe.